# Change tab color when sheet is protected

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to have the tab color change depending on whether a sheet is protected or not?  Eg. protected = green, unprotected = red.

I'm trying to find an easy way to visually spot which sheets are protected.  I have multiple sheets, some I need protected and some I need unprotected.  I edit the protected sheets on a daily basis but I need to protect them when saving so other users don't accidentally edit the data.

Comment: Yes, I have. There is some vba code to change the tab color depending on cell values but nothing on protecting the sheet.

Comment: Please post the code you do have.

Comment: @pnuts I set the protected sheets to limited edits for other users but I have to unprotect it to enter additional data on a daily basis.  I just need to know if there is an easy way to spot if a sheet is protected or not with out having to individually view each one.

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't have any code. I tried to find something similar to work with but the only thing I found changed the tab color based on cell value.  I need it to change based on protected vs. unprotected.

Comment: ...What have you tried? A very quick search shows you can do `x = Sheets("Sheet1").ProtectContents` and it'll return `True/False` depending. Just loop through your worksheets, test for protection, then color as needed.

Comment: @BruceWayne I need the color to automatically change when the protection status changes.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could use the Workbook.Open event. Then every time you open the workbook it will color code all of your worksheets.

Comment: Sure, there's a Workbook.Change event too.

Comment: @BerticusMaximus  I'm not sure how that helps me when I need to know which sheet is protected before I close the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Using what @BruceWayne said. You just need to loop through all your worksheets and check if they're protected. The below code will loop through all then color Green if it's protected or Red if it's unprotected. You can change the event to trigger on whatever action you need. Be sure to put this code IN the workbook and not a module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

    For Each ws In wbk.Worksheets
        If ws.ProtectContents = True Then
            ws.Tab.Color = vbGreen
        Else
            ws.Tab.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```